# Why jQuery DataTables Internationalization i18n doesn't work for me?

Tags: jquery, datatable, internationalization, datatables

I installed and configure the jQuery dataTables plugin in this way:

where $locale = 'Italian';
[from the official dataTables site](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Italian)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $('.data-table').dataTable({
            "language": {
                "url": '<?php echo asset_path("js/datatables/i18n/{$locale}.lang") ?>'
            },
            lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            filter: true,
            sort: true,
            info: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            aoColumnDefs: [
                { bSortable: false, "aTargets": [ -1 ] }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

I tried substituting "language" param with "oLanguage" and "sUrl", but no matter what I do, I still see my dataTables messages in English.

```
....
"oLanguage": {
   "sUrl": '<?php echo asset_path("js/datatables/i18n/{$locale}.lang") ?>'
},
....
```

I think I am doing something wrong, maybe I need first initialize table and only after that call the language, or vice versa before get the language translations and after set the dataTables ... I'm really new with this plugin, if someone can help me, it'd be fantastic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
"language": {
  "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Italian.json"
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/mke35Lrk/.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the fiddle, i change the extension of file from Italian.lang to Italia.json, remove the comment from file and now its work perfectly! But why in the DataTables Plugin repo this file come with .lang extension ... https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/i18n

Comment: Both files are effectively the same. See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/Plugins/master/i18n/Italian.lang and http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/Italian.json. You may find that you just needed to remove the comments from your .lang file to get this working.

Comment: I've tested the .lang files by downloading and saving a local version of the file. With the comments in the file, it does not work, however with the comments removed, it works as expected.